# Simulate flex-direction:row using display:grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to recreate this using `display: grid`
and `gap` instead of `display: flex` and `margin`, without the CSS knowing how many items there are?

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to tell a `display: grid` element that you want extra items to appear in new columns instead of new rows?

Comment: grid-auto-flow: column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grid-auto-flow: column;` on the `id` `#items` with your grid display. This is equivalent to `flex-direction: row;` when using `flex`.

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#items {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
gap:10px;
```

i did not see how many items there are,
Then temani afif got you

```
grid-auto-flow: column;
gap:10px;
``
```